# How to Implement notifications in my Nodejs API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

i'm building an API Using Nodejs and Express and using Mongo DB as my database. and i have several collections:

- Reward
- project
- reward request

also i have three collections for users

- admin
- client
- user

and i need to add notifications to my API but can't find a way to store my notifications in the database since i have different situation for it

- a client must be notified when an admin approve his project

```
{
    sender: admin,
    receiver: client,
    relatedCollection: Project,
    msg: a String
}
```

- an admin must be notified when a client request a project

```
{
    sender: client,
    receiver: admin,
    relatedCollection: Project,
    msg: a String
}
```

- an admin must be notified when a user request a reward

```
{
    sender: user,
    receiver: admin,
    relatedCollection: Reward,
    msg: a String
}
```

so how to implement a notification collection to handle this since the fields may reference different things